# Exclude list in django cannot update

Tags: python, django

Im having a trouble where I cannot filter and update exclude items in Django. I just want to update those item exclude from my list variable. Below is everything I got for now, thanks in advance I appreciate any help and suggestions

> lets say for example I have list

```
  ['1', '2', '5'] and I want to update all of my data in database exclude from 1,2,5 list and update 
 all value into "3"
```

> views.py

```
def update(request):
if request.method=="POST":
    product_ids=request.POST.getlist('id[]')
    for id in product_ids:
        result = Person.objects.filter(province="DATA_1",municipality="Data_2").exclude(pk = 
        id).update(paid=3)
return render(request, 'dashboard.html')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing now is assigning a new queryset to the same variable each time, so you end up with the last one and you never exclude all three at the same time.

What you need to do is exclude multiple items:

```py
Person.objects.filter(
    province="DATA_1",municipality="Data_2"
).exclude(
    pk__in=product_ids
).update(paid=3)
```

See [the bit confusing docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#in):

> In a given iterable; often a list, tuple, or queryset. It’s not a common use case, but strings (being iterables) are accepted.

Basically means, that the `__in` lookup expression expects an iterable, and will filter or exclude all matching items in the iterable.

*NULL data*
Null means no data and is handled differently with __isnull:

```py
Person.objects.filter(
    province="DATA_1",municipality="Data_2"
).exclude(
    street__isnull=True
).update(paid=3)
```

Or:

```
Person.objects.filter(
    province="DATA_1",municipality="Data_2", street__isnull=False
).update(paid=3)
```

Comment: Thank you! , How about I want to exclude all null data from my database like this one [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtH5h.png) I tried  `__in` but it's not working do you know about this?